# for loop check all count together in one loop in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, maps

I am using maps in react native to check whatever the current location matching the a specific location and I am using for loop to check if the location checked 10 times then need to quit and navigate to other screen, but when I used for loop it directly set the count to 10 and navigate to another screen

```
 renderLocationInfo() {
    
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                if (this.state.latitudeR != this.state.latitude && this.state.longitudeR != this.state.longitude) {
                    if (i < 9) {
                        return (
    
                            <View style={styles.container}>
                                <Text style={styles.btn}>Not matching </Text>
    
                            </View>
    
                        );
                    } else {
                        alert("time is out, please try again");
                        this.props.navigation.navigate("dashboard")
                    }
    
                } else if (this.state.latitudeR == this.state.latitude && this.state.longitudeR == this.state.longitude ) {
    
                    return (
    
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <Text style={styles.btn}>Matched</Text>
                            this.props.navigation.navigate("dashboard")
    
                        </View>
    
                    );
    
                }
    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean that in the console the output is `10` at the very beginning?

Comment: @BrettEast yes is like in less than one sec print all numbers till 10 then navigate to other screen, but i want to to check one by one till count set to 10 then exit , because for every check i am printing text on screen

Comment: Where in your function is the actual location checking happening? Is it in the `<View />` component? I think I just need a little more context, but I suspect the issue is that you're making an asynchronous call inside a `for` loop which won't behave as you want it to here.

Comment: @BrettEast in the two `if else` statements happened which i am comparing coords of the current location with specific coords i have it stored in states

Comment: @BrettEast it is return the View inside the if statement but the problem is that the for loop is quit so fast it doesn't set the i in ascending order  even when i console.log the i from the first time it print  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: I'm still a little confused with what you're trying to do, what makes the coordinates change, like why would you check it 10 times rather than just one time? what happens at each step that might update that if statement to be true/false? Or are you just trying to add like a counter to the screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229140/discussion-between-brett-east-and-anie).